# Как раздобыть старые программерские мануалы к макинтошу?

Tags: документация, mac

Приветствую!

Есть у меня [дрѣвнiй докумѣнтъ](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/mac/pdf/Operating_System_Utilities/MLU.pdf), который является отдельной главой программерского мануала к макинтошу. Я его прочитал, пара вопросов прояснилось, еще несколько добавилось. Хочется другие главы почитать, но до той директории совершенно невозможно добраться. Где бы остальные PDFы раздобыть?

Answer (score 2):

1) Установить XCode.

2) Выбрать в меню:

XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads ->Documentation

Появится список модулей документации. Выбрать

Mac OS X Legacy Library

и загрузить ее. Это примерно 900 МБайт.

После загрузки вся информация доступна через поисковую систему XCode и м ожет быть экспортирована в PDF.

Comment: То есть у них PDF - не первичный формат? Спасибо, займусь.